# Out parameters in ARC Objective-C

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease

I'm using Objective-C, and I don't know how to create and call a method with out parameters when compiling the code with the ARC compiler.

This is the kind of thing I'm trying to accomplish in non-ARC Objective-C (this is probably wrong anyway).

```
//
//  Dummy.m
//  OutParamTest

#import "Dummy.h"

@implementation Dummy

- (void) foo {
    NSString* a = nil;
    [self barOutString:&a];
    NSLog(@"%@", a);
}

- (void) barOutString:(NSString **)myString {
    NSString* foo = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"hello"];
    *myString = foo;
}

@end
```

I've read the documentation here:
https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

and here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html

...but am finding it difficult to get anything that compiles, never mind anything that is correct. Would anybody be able to rewrite the jist of the code above, in a way that is suitable for ARC Objective-C?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What compiler errors do you get?

Comment: I've updated the code sample above with your suggestions, and included the set of compiler errors. Thanks.

Comment: See my updated answer. As the compiler says, you cannot use an indirect pointer like that, instead you must pass in `&a` directly.

Comment: Thanks for your help @MikeWeller, the code above compiles now - is it technically correct?

Comment: You don't need the `b` variable, just pass in `&a` as the argument. You also don't need to use `__autoreleasing` on the `a` and `b` variables unless you need to access the initial value in `barOutString:` which isn't very common.

Comment: Yep, sorry, missed your comment. I was getting very muddled with the pointers there. Looks ok now then? Thanks.

Comment: NSString* foo = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"hello"] autorelease];
Gives me "ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease'"
This compiles though:
   NSString __autoreleasing* foo = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"hello"];

Comment: Arg. What was I thinking? Sorry, yes the code is correct now. Of course you don't need autorelease with ARC -_-

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the `__autoreleasing` attribute on the out parameter:

```
- (void) barOutString:(NSString * __autoreleasing *)myString {
    NSString* foo = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"hello"];
    *myString = foo;
}
```

The prerelease documentation (which I'm not allowed to link to due to NDA) puts the `__autoreleasing` in the middle of the two '*'s, but it might just work as `(__autoreleasing NSString **)`

You also cannot use an indirect double pointer (`b`) as in your original code. You must use this form:

```
- (void) foo {
    NSString* a = nil;
    [self barOutString:&a];
    NSLog(@"%@", a);
}
```

You are also calling `dealloc` directly on an object which is completely wrong. I suggest you read the memory management guidelines.

Comment: There's a small error in the first method.  `*myString = &foo;` should be changed to `*myString = foo;`.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. Not sure how that got in there.